# Contact forms on circle bundles whose fibres are Reeb orbits

Tags: differential-topology, symplectic-geometry, contact-topology

Let $\pi: M \to \Sigma$ be a circle bundle over a closed surface $\Sigma$. When does $M$ admit a contact form whose Reeb orbits are the fibres of this bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are known as Boothby-Wang fibrations. There are conditions that can be studied to say when your question can be positively answered. You can check Geiges Introduction to Contact Topology in Section 7.2.